# Will the Ubuntu installer delete my HP recovery drive?

Tags: system-installation

When installing Ubuntu, if I select the option which says it'll erase *all* data on my computer, does that include the HP recovery drive?

Comment: All data = all data.

Comment: Yes, it does. You need to use the Something Else option. Search the site. There's lots of questions on this.

Comment: already did >:-D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

The best option (in my opinion) is to always use "something else". Remove the partitions you want erased. Recreate partitions as you want and do not mount and do not format the recovery partition.